# how to make 256 ppi avd in new version avd android

Tags: android, ppi, android-virtual-device

i want to make avd  for **Moto E** device specification but for **moto e** device has   **256 ppi pixel density**  so when i create avd in new version there are no any option for make custom avd with custom ppi see below image.

[image]

Any idea how can i make **Moto E** device avd?

**EDIT**

**In 480 x 800 resolution device**

[image]

**In 540 x 960 resolution device**

[image]

in my dimen.xml i give value

```
  <dimen name="text_normal">10sp</dimen>
```

**my row.xml is look like below**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/selectore_listview"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/drawer_properties" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_itemName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drawer_icon"
            android:text="dfdsjgfhgdj"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_big_normal" 
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
              />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img_add_rbn"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_add_rbn"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_add_rbn"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_counter"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="00"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" 
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
              />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_add_rbn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/drawer_rbn_addnew"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and i set this value in counter value of manage property which is gray in my image so you can see difference in **480x800** screen it look nice but in **540x960** it comes very small so any idea how can i solve it?.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option for ppi because android devices are scaled in density(dpi).

Instead what you need to do is to find a **dpi** for your device which has 256ppi,540x960, and 4.3 in size.

Here is the sample of it taken from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Motorola_Mobility)

```
11 (4.3)    540x960 101 (256)   1.5 hdpi
```

That device is using **hdpi** as density which is equivalent to 256ppi that you are trying to find.

Comment: :: ya but i wnat ot maintain my layout in 480x800 as well as 540x960 device resolution so i make emulator with 540x960 resolution with 240 dpi but when i run my app in actual Moto E device than at that time all textsize value getting very small..

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya " i wnat ot maintain my layout in 480x800 as well as 540x960 " it will automatically resize the layout for you instead if you have images, for textsize you need to use your values folder for different value of the size of your device.

Comment: @ Rod_Algonquin :i already make folder for that like value-hdpi,value-mdpi,values-xhdpi but in 540x960 resolution device take textsize value from values-hdpi which is compatible for 480x800 so when i run my application in 540x960 resolution device it getting small ..

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya can you post an image of textview of 480x800 and 540x960

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya is the setting for 480x800 of avd is hdpi??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58537/discussion-between-harshal-kalavadiya-and-rod-algonquin).

Comment: @ Rod_Algonquin::  see my answer but i also mark you answer +1 because it is also give some hint to me.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for 540 x 960 resolution device value.xml . i make folder file for 540x960 resolution device as **values-sw360dp** and inside it i make **dimens.xml** file for that and it is working for me.

by using below formula i create value folder for 540 x 960 device

```
px=540 width of device

dp=240 density of device

dp=(px/dp)*160
  =(540/240)*160
  =360
```

so finally create values folder like **values-360dp** for **540x960** device. And you can create other folder fo rmaking combination of screen width and density of device and make UI interface good for that.

**for 480x800 devcie**

```
res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml
```

**for 540x960 device**

```
res/values-sw360dp/dimens.xml
```